# Laravel 5.3 - Model que pode ser criado por múltiplos Controllers

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, relacionamento

Boa tarde, uso Laravel 5.3 como back-end de um projeto e vou tentar explicar da maneira mais sucinta o problema.

**Problema**: No meu projeto tenho o model Duplicata e o Contrato.

1. Um contrato cria várias duplicatas pelo ContratoController
2. Uma duplicata pode ser criada por outro controlador chamado LocacaoController.
3. E por fim a duplicata pode ser criada pelo DuplicataController via método store().

No banco de dados tenho as tabelas:

```
duplicatas
contratos
```

Todos eles compartilham basicamente o mesmo código

```
$duplicata = new Duplicata()
$duplicata->valor = $request->valor
$duplicata->descricao = $request->descricao
$duplicata->contrato_id = $request->contrato_id
$duplicata->save()
```

Porém agora vou adicionar o nossoNúmero no banco de dados, e vou ter que copiar e colar a lógica de programação em todos os 3 controladores.

E achei isso uma bad prática de programação e pretendo unificar o modo em como as duplicatas são criadas, mas como eu faço isso? Estou fazendo tudo errado?

Comment: Crie as Duplicatas apenas no DuplicataController, injete a dependencia onde você precisa que crie duplicatas e utiliza apenas o metodo store de DuplicataController, não faz sentido por a mesma função em um monte de lugares diferentes se você pode reutilizar :)

Comment: Mas apenas esse método se repete? Caso queira, você pode criar um Controller específico (ex: DuplicadoresController) com os métodos que serão compartilhados e dar um "extend" dele nos 3 controllers que precisa.

Comment: Ou cria uma classe que faz isso chama no App\NomeDaClasse e invoca a função. GGWP.

Comment: O negócio é que quando um contrato é criado o sistema dispara uma série de criação de duplicatas a partir dos parâmetros passados (vencimento, valor do contrato, etc) via transaction, pois caso dê algum erro na criação de uma o contrato inteiro é apagado.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold no caso da injeção de um Controller em outro como eu chamaria o método store? E o que fazer com o retorno dele? (return response()->json('Duplicata criada com sucesso, 200'))?

Comment: @Cassiano criei uma resposta mais ou menos com uma direção para você seguir, existem várias maneiras de fazer isso de forma elegante, espero que ajude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie esse método dentro de um `Controller` de `Duplicata`:

```
public function criaDuplicata($request)
{
    $duplicata = new Duplicata()
    $duplicata->create($request);
    return $duplicata;
}

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->criaDuplicata($request->all());
        return view("suaView", []);
    }
```

E chame ela inclusive no seu `store` que recebe um `Request`. Assim você pode usar essa dependencia em outros lugares, por exemplo em `ContratoController`.

```
public function __construct(DuplicataController $duplicataController) //Aqui está a injeção de dependência
{
    $this->duplicataController = $duplicataController;
}

public function geraDuplicata($duplicata)
{
    $this->duplicataController->criaDuplicata($duplicata);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu criei uma pasta chamada **Classes** dentro de **App**.
E criei um arquivo com o nome da classe.

Tipo no seu caso pode ser `CadastroDuplicata`.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Classes;

    class CadastroDuplicata{
        public static function create($request){
            $duplicata              = new Duplicata()
            $duplicata->valor       = $request->valor
            $duplicata->descricao   = $request->descricao
            $duplicata->contrato_id = $request->contrato_id
            $duplicata->save();
        }
    }
```

### Controller

```
use App\Classes\CadastroDuplicata

.
.
.

CadastroDuplicata::create($request);
```

Daí você chama a função em qualquer outro Controller dessa forma, pode criar mais parâmetros também.
Não esquece de chamar a classe dos **Models** na **Classe**.

Melhor ainda você pode fazer isso no **Model** da **Duplicata**. Criar essa mesma função lá dentro ao invés de criar uma classe numa pasta separada.

Eu fiz assim porquê eu gosto.

Comment: Eu gostei da resposta, mas a dúvida que ficou é: Foge um pouco dos padrões do Laravel de MVC. Manutenir esse modelo no futuro seria um problema?

Comment: Isso é Orientação a Objeto. Certamente seria lícito fazer isso e é de fácil manutenção.

Answer (score 2):

Já foi mostrado injeção (*IMHO* a melhor), método estático, então vamos a mais uma alternativa e tu vê qual se adapta melhor ao que precisa.

O que precisa pode ser feito a partir de herança:

```
abstract class podeDuplicar extends BaseController{

    public function gerarDuplicata(){
        $duplicata = new Duplicata();
        $duplicata->valor = $request->valor;
        $duplicata->descricao = $request->descricao;
        $duplicata->contrato_id = $request->contrato_id;
        $duplicata->save();
    }

}
```

Logo, só dar o `extend`:

```
class ContratoController extends podeDuplicar { /* Resto da lógica aqui */ }
class LocacaoController extends podeDuplicar { /* Resto da lógica aqui */ }
class DuplicataController extends podeDuplicar { /* Resto da lógica aqui */ }
```

Então qualquer um pode simplesmente fazer:

```
(new ContratoController)->gerarDuplicata();
(new LocacaoController)->gerarDuplicata();
(new DuplicataController)->gerarDuplicata();
```

E se quiser manter o `store()` do `DuplicataController`, só puxar o método:

```
class DuplicataController extends podeDuplicar {
    public function store(){ 
        $this->gerarDuplicata();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria, então [traits](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php), que é uma prática utilizada no `framework` [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), onde os `controllers` podem herdam essa código.

***Exemplo***

`trait`

```
trait DuplicatasOfControllers
{
    public function inserirDuplicata(Request $request) 
    {
        $duplicata              = new Duplicata()
        $duplicata->valor       = $request->valor
        $duplicata->descricao   = $request->descricao
        $duplicata->contrato_id = $request->contrato_id
        $duplicata->save();
    }
}
```

---

`controllers`

```
class ContratoController 
{
    use DuplicatasOfControllers;
}

class DuplicataController 
{
    use DuplicatasOfControllers;

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->inserirDuplicata($request);
        return view("suaView", []);
    }
}

class LocacaoController
{
    use DuplicatasOfControllers;
}
```

As mudanças ocorridos no código de duplicatas serão feitas no `trait DuplicatasOfControllers`.